# making html table sortable (with headers and data loaded using javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html in a website:

```
<table id="list" class="tablesorter">
  <thead id="header">
  </thead>
  <tbody id="rows">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I load the header and rows of the table using javascript. Example of how I fill the headers:

```
$.get( '/getdata',{}, function(mydata) {    

        // Parses JSON Into Array
        var array = $.parseJSON(mydata);
        var html = '<tr>';
        html+='<th>#</th>';
        html+='<th>One</th>';
        html+='<th">TOTAL</th>';
        var available = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            available_item = array[i];
            html+='<th><abbr title="'+array[i].text+'"><img src="img/flags2/'+array[i].country+'.png"></img></abbr></th>';
        };
        html += '</tr>';
        $(html).appendTo('#header');
});
```

The rows are filled in a similar way: ajax get, for loop, and append to html.

Now I need the table columns to be sortable. 
I was trying to get it work with [jquery tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) but it is not working. I suppose that it is not working because my data is loaded using javascript.

How can I make this table sortable?

Comment: Make sure you're calling the tablesorter plugin after the table is created (`$(html).appendTo('#header');`)- I've done this in the past and it works nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add $("#list").tablesorter(); at the end (when table is already filled with all data, thead and tbody)... I am using the same in my application and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

use below code. add `$("#list").tablesorter();` at data loop end.

```
$.get( '/getdata',{}, function(mydata) {    

    // Parses JSON Into Array
    var array = $.parseJSON(mydata);
    var html = '<tr>';
    html+='<th>#</th>';
    html+='<th>One</th>';
    html+='<th">TOTAL</th>';
    var available = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        available_item = array[i];
        html+='<th><abbr title="'+array[i].text+'"><img src="img/flags2/'+array[i].country+'.png"></img></abbr></th>';

       if(array.length === (i+1)){
           html += '</tr>';
           $(html).appendTo('#header');
           $("#list").tablesorter(); 
        }
    };

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes you can do it**

Looking at your title *making html table sortable (with headers and data loaded using javascript)*

It doest matter if you are loading data via jquery or simply using php ... 
look for datatables in bootstrap .. [This plugin](https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap) provides all types of data manipulation with the tables that also includes sorting of the data ... you can also perform search in the table. All you have to do is give your table some id like "mytable" then write

```
$(document).ready( function () {
     $('#mytable').DataTable();

} );
```

after that you can start to include different attributes to select the type of sorting searching etc ... hope that helps